# How to get value from json string?

Tags: python, json

I'm using an api for xboxapi.com and most of its information is formatted in json.

The following json code has information about current "Games with Gold" offers from Xbox. I would like to set each game name to its own variable for example:

```
Game1 = Sleeping Dogs: Definitive Edition
Game2 = Outlast
```

and so on. The key I'm trying to extract is "TitleName" which I see multiple times:

```
{u'DealsWithGold': [{u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcn7qrFTCgrdsYZolKQCspp4SoQw.653_omjxeLZZcEjFId7w2ZbAm6Xp866uW2L036n68.GIvHWDJIRg1_RVNXNRgcZ2rzi2XquNyG4Y8pway34MGXwqQt04yF1OhntP54QP3aVBytfXKBsCtYMhwwMm4xSPEsvQKw6qRWjFtd6I-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa339.99', u'TitleId': 173291706, u'ReleaseDate': u'22/09/2015 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa310.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'b039ee32-12b7-42c1-877e-f612853822f8', u'TitleName': u'Blood Bowl 2'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTca.i0ev_ROgDHN4WvTtO_Gw0a_IjTeyM7ESdn7DRxY2wG88LE7i050FLXSvRE1wpzzWmu6MH_6dD2yuVOiCvDIIp4rcjoLX5FxzIe5KadMqyKKsyUYc7G9wp8A75PeBdbTqu0RFb9oDo8wWVXekOP_8F0RXHZjW3u8cSuQguV9D4-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa37.99', u'TitleId': 324157644, u'ReleaseDate': u'01/06/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa34.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'9c5c1bfc-1b9e-46c1-a25d-42eb29f3bd63', u'TitleName': u'Fragments of Him'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTc8VAGY5Cv9TFzPEVvREk9IOLTu2W2skQj5fSidvj2_aU35ri9UH4OiG9LMxRKzV4VFSLExoN.mKvj16y2VHAnW9ElkbBRrWkm_7XCfirZ5I.YW.j.K65sZNcKe2NG3fzHTU_pcBsjC9f5zSTZ6m7G0CREL2zdzNlGQ0eNiam52sg-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa311.99', u'TitleId': 708889423, u'ReleaseDate': u'21/10/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa36.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'0ff9004a-f280-42b5-beaf-efd926a29e82', u'TitleName': u'Slain: Back from Hell'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTciGdM3OcWpFcwYgD7ujzBJFaG_DCe9H3p5.esXU_S4SuLSxirselyhyzUrzt7_KDl4Tav3jjGgKpj.TYiD5N1QaGBjZGO0fR6Wb3ymcDebkmgdYBzB.2UJcj6o.bt1McG0nXxkjA85358Em5jMWb16dZLN3M7XotRifxN_e8DTVU-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa323.99', u'TitleId': 385764340, u'ReleaseDate': u'15/07/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa312.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'47858f86-9d5c-4888-882c-19e5a6f999db', u'TitleName': u'MX vs. ATV Supercross Encore'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTca8_Pe9ZuLWb5eJUbFiW9qAC3VyqYZW0Pr2AxBGozGqPvcHpwzO87fFe.czPWC24xdG0A87S9w2y.LjNzAhLEur5_ybb.UYEizfZM2OEFGB6bRX9fK8DnzQe_z5Eny1_8BrHoCTEWrfI9Qp4NFoTP4uf7E0vSZg.St2MO2frVAKQ-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa315.99', u'TitleId': 828985924, u'ReleaseDate': u'29/03/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa38.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'd17c7138-fa59-4dc8-987c-eb5873f1f317', u'TitleName': u'Resident Evil 6'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcC_BySz8A0VNYqrhSViCnY4zACWteZotF0F6yREkqEniW0Va8TbJE3IFEiCfdbPhQHxCkU6zRJ8sGYFcWuN5wEQaIcK2LR8FJTlxTgITO4uNfjQYVwyIliPYe_A09czTimpoYiRLq9aABqdVXEImstob.C.aWmDa0yoJacQMJ61Y-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa315.19', u'TitleId': 77954319, u'ReleaseDate': u'21/08/2015 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa33.04', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'50b961ea-f1d5-4615-9e33-93cae9558a29', u'TitleName': u'Never Alone Arctic Collection'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcOrESyQr6Shih9EdFPEc6jAOsyrHiNAI79OBFQkJmg3.07jWeJamDJ4j5yzXs8EVnNcFZzYRAVbe.1GU0fpYy03MnYIhOKzZUdUMVJQhEONm7uJc3i9588TeLtkU5fWvC7T0wWqyOCnpUdurtyDUYnziHGiTXLykIEhKBO4jE5A0-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa319.99', u'TitleId': 240091546, u'ReleaseDate': u'03/05/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa313.39', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'0856a106-226c-48cc-a062-fe9fcec37ddb', u'TitleName': u'SUPERHOT'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcBTXCCwevUKD503h8xffAMGudiLwE54NR9kTV0YQDmNbEHO.O46Qy1tP391wc7hRrUUwgwnSEnvnB849yN7CfzTyB6r_qc3TBJdDvhmYMYz9m.s64FgvPZo_sU0sqw61JiTaAnL687ZLFI2Y_qmuk8K2y0lZ9n24o5aSMLtVWnS0-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa344.99', u'TitleId': 1161955801, u'ReleaseDate': u'28/06/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa311.25', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'9f769e96-5c8f-4c26-a8bb-2661b3b6a37f', u'TitleName': u'The Technomancer'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcI_SHUnYfpXKFYMJD810IWw42qIAh4BWKmggm0sxHteV4z8q0t_UPkIlMsNkOVNJYHGvVw.Xq6ZaKk9u96XxHuExwH.wTOEj.FoRzxi0pkHCZlvmYL6_dvxRDPz9arL916lK4olVx2XiwpL6K5tMZD4bEV5fuXJXBuSjCp9B_xH4-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa315.99', u'TitleId': 939455454, u'ReleaseDate': u'30/08/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa38.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'3a446e44-a6ec-46de-9b18-b419454b06e8', u'TitleName': u'resident evil 4'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTc5kSXAr.8jrkqBXXGG_69EU1lmeXc_8FTKmInbif4h10FFZXiwVcnejsMLFO2muZBd0823wMM9qETRxOBu8wQeBzQgODguQGH6aMw_dgJGR.OeYkhaC0TsXV8l_42_tQ9YrrNSBb.IE_PlwUVm5vHcQHAh5FblQQ1hr8bcFH8CIo-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa323.99', u'TitleId': 2090746416, u'ReleaseDate': u'29/08/2014 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa34.80', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'db00744e-d1f4-48c6-a263-9127851f2ad1', u'TitleName': u'Metro Redux Bundle'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcOfWEdfOmWpUzeJd6viYs3VgDjiOIzo.in19q7EHPefusnoBX7lAHk2fiqKMoYfY_omI1G0UHpfiLOHHIdQo66gz50qrrS.UTsmB4A45GhblyVCJmfH8T9e0j4SwMbACmmoJU1GFjo3LABzNlMrUbxpnFr3pwNf19BoKvd5UB9i0-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa319.99', u'ReleaseDate': u'09/10/2015 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa313.99', u'MediaItemType': u'DConsumable', u'ID': u'115ee730-6ba4-43cc-b9fb-aa6ea30fe062', u'TitleName': u'Case of Gold (3250)'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcWQSV7WC52m0wJF_wKq7lN6XJgyvo0yoNYzUE4pPIAL_MChAfOKt58lUBCghRycfh6_4PsMTJs4AG5xGccE_0ZsqBXTOghvjpEcHZyf.JAt1Ae_wwwPVKmythJgvNreaGynTwJy1JZK0iNuvqPcbESUKm7DuETwT21A5ixqL6ZN0-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa315.99', u'TitleId': 568218779, u'ReleaseDate': u'28/06/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa38.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'69a27e70-cd9c-4dcf-a33b-9e3f8730bec6', u'TitleName': u'RESIDENT EVIL 5'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcYeIIQ5.i4l.lZuxrg9LbUCkAsOXlNRRehmq0VcOwuQFApKLt5RKGWgo259FPPs5pcG0QjWI5gbbUoDvF_IAVN1_0rTPHxnPp9nPWKrmsmXvNo8FjHOudkzCP0AZhtrN5YQc_GixwR7gG8Wh6pZqKNz0kUnwDK1bzd9s3JvP1R38-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa323.99', u'TitleId': 856892583, u'ReleaseDate': u'27/10/2015 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa36.00', u'MediaItemType': u'DGame', u'ID': u'c44f3f25-99cb-4ad6-91bd-dc491b6f7cd7', u'TitleName': u'Darksiders II Deathinitive Edition'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcleyMha0_6UT3es0IylPrTiRD00xVHwJbT2q2dRsfqkoJBSER.NzOAid1tt0fkja8DmV5306K.PVLL8fqtXDFAPsFXJ5Nk_shOfiAgeJ_KPy9z3hsdRTJ7yf37BHlqLXa7UwlZY14XmPeP1J4Dmjgo47MyaH6AKLr_jxwAv30KTI-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa37.99', u'ReleaseDate': u'20/04/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa35.59', u'MediaItemType': u'DConsumable', u'ID': u'95946dbc-48d8-4974-86d5-89fd2f123bc7', u'TitleName': u'City of Gems (1200)'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTc.7pgxOh3A9IkQi79aQDL3tPj877ie.C6EUciAM9HXt7D66KjCJwi7CKXx2L5DymGtCx16fZn5S.Xi0fzv145Njm8aVU5IiIcCcAQaoYlEoHD_wrWggjMynPBZIlZET8tFFNDHjMKn4Zh3JWGDRd_avS7XQ2OYmUyc64H318lZo4-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa36.79', u'ReleaseDate': u'23/02/2016 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa32.24', u'MediaItemType': u'DDurable', u'ID': u'e9fda946-c318-48d2-ac1e-f1b63bef059e', u'TitleName': u'The Escapists DLC Bundle'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTc1ToETtpPwWtAjk.8Hf10b20KiBepqCWyFqz4nk2DCZt1xZoZSv3Knp3zu5KdVMrn445E0BpGi96AuVFd07YfRWv_jRA7DNjtPRS_D5_XNRznghlO6lxI3ZmQ2xpJPFa9blgyxuFDDJj0XGj_.oXbO.kOPFcsIcHztx7P3LMr8ww-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa315.99', u'ReleaseDate': u'15/09/2015 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'\xa39.59', u'MediaItemType': u'DDurable', u'ID': u'40609baa-6699-4ff7-8f4c-5909888378cb', u'TitleName': u'Destiny: The Taken King'}], u'GamesWithGold': [{u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTcHdIJ5tipiEIbOwd9Qp.QcvjgOWU68DqNLV7Y3_ceFi6qMfkih9MIXx62yDnFb8CQ5lyFbpaWHSZ2DhQedPmjAm2v4daZh1cTEXP6ov4f45QekCZOI0ozUt9TSqP7By3m45rrd8ICwu_mFCpXr9HwixGGJCQxC3uCHe9ztRNveaA-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa315.99', u'TitleId': 196423588, u'ReleaseDate': u'19/06/2014 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'Free with', u'SubscriptionImage': u'https://compass-ssl.xboxlive.com/assets/1f/b4/1fb4b510-25e9-4271-ba3e-4d2e2d952c53.png?n=gold-wht.png', u'ID': u'e30cee6d-748d-4356-98bb-3471ed257ade', u'TitleName': u'Outlast'}, {u'TitleImage': u'http://images-eds.xboxlive.com/image?url=8Oaj9Ryq1G1_p3lLnXlsaZgGzAie6Mnu24_PawYuDYIoH77pJ.X5Z.MqQPibUVTc3zp_MzcvOnFpNoimrfkmDO1EL_NQwQsYGhqGfz.39jHyK6FmqXJnrLHxWgzYob2xp_shCzR5i1Ku00ybKNwxs9XPp3K.YLuc3Ta4XQnqjcPiX.QIirfXaw9LQi.bAEgM8SeGhIQkyjAEr.96peTNzDZrHvE1HJ1_ILUvxZqqpTY-&w=282&h=424&format=jpg', u'ListPriceText': u'\xa323.99', u'TitleId': 367254866, u'ReleaseDate': u'10/10/2014 00:00:00', u'DiscountedPriceText': u'Free with', u'SubscriptionImage': u'https://compass-ssl.xboxlive.com/assets/1f/b4/1fb4b510-25e9-4271-ba3e-4d2e2d952c53.png?n=gold-wht.png', u'ID': u'cc9cac48-36b3-4574-85e3-965abe32b133', u'TitleName': u'Sleeping Dogs\u2122 Definitive Edition'}]}


#This Variable holds the data 
GWG = api.get_xboxone_gold()
json_str = json.dumps(GWG) 
resp = json.loads(json_str)
print (resp) 
print(resp["TitleName"])
```

Comment: That isn't json it's already a python dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do or why. Why do you want to "set each game name to its own variable"? What makes you think that would be a good idea?

Comment: And where's the code you wrote to attempt this?

Comment: I want to make an interface that uses those game names in a clean way. I want to be able to call on each game individually if I want to search the game on google or such. So I could call Game1 and it would be equal to Sleeping Dogs: Definitive Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear you already parsed whatever JSON you received, so next step is to parse the dictionary.

> `print(resp["TitleName"])`
>
> No matter the approach I try, I can't find "TitleName"

Put your JSON here. (Not the python data, the actual JSON) https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com

You'll clearly notice that TitleName is not a top level element. You have to loop over the gold deals element.

For example, list comprehension

```
names = [x['TitleName'] for x in data['DealsWithGold']]
```

Or, the more verbose version which you can extend to get more data than just the title

```
names = [] 
games = data['DealsWithGold']
for game in games:
    names.append(game['TitleName'])
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir! I appreciate you clarifying on my misunderstanding. 
This gives me a list that I can most definitely work with! 
I now think I understand how lists work thanks to you! 
I can't thank you enough, sir.

Comment: Beware: the shown dict contains **2** lists of dicts, and the title OP said he was interested in are in the other one...

Comment: True. Both lists have the title name, though, so I'll leave that as a learning exercise.

Comment: I noticed that. All I had to do was change "DealsWithGold" to "GamesWithGold".

Comment: Regardless, I was going to use both dicts. I just needed a way to find one in a readable format so I could get the other information I needed.